# Python: How to call a parent class (super()) method with using objects from children's attributes?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, super

**EDIT:**
I am having trouble with calling a method of the parent  class.

1. Working code example:

```py
from datetime import datetime


class GlobalState:
    def __init__(self, ui):
        self.state = "old"
        self.dict_stateWidgets = {"date": None,
                                  "time": None,
                                  "image": None}
        self.setState("old")

    def setState(self, str_newState: str):
        self.state = str_newState
        self.updateControlledWidgets()

    def extractDateAndTime(self):
        dict_dateTime = {"date": str(),
                         "time": str()}
        timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(1434549820776 / 1000)
        dict_dateTime["date"] = timestamp.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")
        dict_dateTime["time"] = timestamp.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
        return dict_dateTime

    def updateTimeWidget(self):
        dict_dateTime = self.extractDateAndTime()
        self.dict_stateWidgets["date"].setText(dict_dateTime["date"])
        self.dict_stateWidgets["time"].setText(dict_dateTime["time"])

    def updateControlledWidgets(self):
        self.updateTimeWidget()


class CloudState(GlobalState):
    def __init__(self, main_ui):
        super().__init__(ui=main_ui)
        self.ui = main_ui
        self.dict_stateWidgets = {"date": self.ui.l_cloud_date,
                                  "time": self.ui.l_cloud_time,
                                  "image": self.ui.l_cloud_image}

    def setState(self, str_newState: str):
        super().setState(str_newState)
        print("Some more class-specific actions to be done here")



class Widget():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def setText(self, str_text):
        print(str_text)


class MainWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l_cloud_date = Widget("date")
        self.l_cloud_time = Widget("time")
        self.l_cloud_image = Widget("image")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ui = MainWindow()
    cs = CloudState(ui)
    cs.setState("newState")
```

2. Expected output:
   Print output of self.ui.l_cloud_date.setText()
3. Error:

> in updateTimeWidget
> self.dict_stateWidgets["date"].setText(dict_dateTime["date"])
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setText'

I thought I could implement the function in GlobalState and inherit it to CloudState and the super() operator just works with the CloudState object in the GlobalState-implementation... Can someone help ?

Comment: Please just paste in your actual code. The way you have split everything up into snippets is too confusing. Also include the full error traceback.

Comment: Sounds like `GlobalState.__init__` is getting called *after* `CloudState.__init__` is initializing `self.dict_stateWidgets`, meaning your non-`None` values are being overwritten. Please provide a [mcve] instead an incomplete step-by-step breakdown of what you think you are doing.

Comment: There is an `Edit` button available for your question here in case you don't know. I strongly suggest you use it and provide a MRE as @chepner said. 1) Complete copy-pastable code reduced to the essentials for the actual problem at hand, 2) expected/desired output for that code, 3) actual output/error (full stack trace).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Parent class methods called through a Child instance using `super().method` can still access the child instance's attributes through `self`. For example, see [this TIO](https://tio.run/##lY6xCsMgFEV3v@LVpQolS7dCpy7t1j8QMUoEtRLNIKXfbjWChEzt267Xczk@xenlzjkLw0OAJ5@lixcE5UapgDHtdGSMBGkUbe/1ahwctxKugBuEUacCT6yWe8rP2kWi8F2fwCZYeR3g3dc@mCLUTG6TNiNp0/RPoZX9wScsXs6EDr2nO1X8OFrgIOreobr5Mt@cyl9RQtOszXZFbELOXw), which prints `My name is Child` when `Child().say_name()` is called, even though `Child().say_name()` calls `super().say_name()`

Comment: In fact, if all you do in `CloudState.setState` is call `super.setState`, you don't even need to define that function in the child class, since it's already inherited from the parent

Comment: Added a reduced code example to copy-paste as Daniil suggested.

setState should do some more things additionally to the GlobalState.setState method.

Comment: Okay I got the problem. It is the "self.setState("old")" line in "GlobalState". Calls itself and receives None-Types. Thanks to chepner, that solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to remove

```
self.setState("old").
```

It was quite a big code already and I did not see that setState worked with the GlobalState constructor attributes.

Thanks to chepner for the hint and of course thanks to all of you for your help.